# Unable to create New Webapplication: WebConfigModification

Tags: web-application, configuration

I'm tying to create a new WebAppp in my farm through CA - UI . 
But in the end of job, the window throws an exception with "Connection failed."

In my logs I find this msg:

> WebConfigModification: Changes not applied to web application
>   [webApp Name]- Test with Url http://

It seems like the process could not finish to write something  into the new WebApp Web.Config. 
 If I create a new Site collection with root, it does it but when I try to call the new SC URl  it doesn't work!

Logs when trying to access to the new WebApp SC:

```
"05/26/2015 10:46:06.17 w3wp.exe (0x10F8)   0x2570  SharePoint Server Search    Query   fla3    High    SearchServiceApplication::Execute--Correlation Id: 23810e79-d168-4cc1-b0a1-424f03c499a7 44137394-58de-4389-839e-ca376abe5d5f    " "05/26/2015 10:46:00.46   w3wp.exe (0x10F8)   0x2570  SharePoint Server Search    Query   fla3    High    SearchServiceApplication::Execute--Correlation Id: 23810e79-d168-4cc1-b0a1-424f03c499a7 05543292-9730-4d80-a365-8359665928ff    " "05/26/2015 10:45:49.94   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x226C  Web Content Management  Site Management c07h    High    SpawnVariationSitesJob has started  2ca23db7-9990-4d2e-9c86-12493a5bd1c0    " "05/26/2015 10:45:49.94   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x226C  Web Content Management  Site Management c07i    High    SpawnVariationSitesJob has finished. Time Spent: 00:00:00.0019542   2ca23db7-9990-4d2e-9c86-12493a5bd1c0    " "05/26/2015 10:45:42.87   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x226C  Web Content Management  Site Management c07h    High    VariationCreateSites has started    d7bcf9cd-b30b-4ee0-82a3-711cc3977ac6    " "05/26/2015 10:45:42.87   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x226C  Web Content Management  Site Management c07i    High    VariationCreateSites has finished. Time Spent: 00:00:00.0009771 d7bcf9cd-b30b-4ee0-82a3-711cc3977ac6    " "05/26/2015 10:45:40.85   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x2AC8  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  dkd5    High    synchronizing search service instance   cc408d73-5739-4857-bae2-3f76cca5b5ff    " "05/26/2015 10:45:40.85   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x2AC8  SharePoint Server Search    Administration  eff0    High    synchronizing search data access service instance   cc408d73-5739-4857-bae2-3f76cca5b5ff    " "05/26/2015 10:45:36.82   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x2A7C  Web Content Management  Site Management c07h    High    VariationCreateSites has started    f8392065-d195-4d13-bbb8-9244dc348950    " "05/26/2015 10:45:36.82   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x2A7C  Web Content Management  Site Management c07i    High    VariationCreateSites has finished. Time Spent: 00:00:00.0009771 f8392065-d195-4d13-bbb8-9244dc348950    " "05/26/2015 10:45:27.74   OWSTIMER.EXE (0x2584)   0x2AC8  Web Content Management  Site Management c07h    High    VariationCreateSites has started    2bdd61ce-9bf3-4b21-9aa9-3998403ca4be    "
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem when you already have some web applications in your trunk. Looks like you got lots of them so i'm sure this is applicable for you.

I'm gonna quote my old answer to the same question.

> This is usually because you either have too many Web Applications in your SharePoint Server, or because your SharePoint Server is slow! As part of the Web Application creation process, SharePoint resets IIS. By Default, the application pool only allows for 90 seconds for all the connections to close before it down by force. If you got this message it’s because 90 seconds wasn’t enough and we need to increase that limit.
>
> I found the solution here, and it worked perfectly. Go into IIS and
>   change the property "shutdown time limit" for the central admin
>   application pool from 90 to 300 seconds.

[Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage when creating new Web Application in SharePoint 2013](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/11/internet-explorer-display-webpage-creating-new-web-application-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Unable to create new web application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103487/unable-to-create-new-web-application)

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you do it for the central admin web application on your application server and did a iisreset afterwards?

Comment: Exactly! App pool of CA on my App Server! IIS Reset as well!

Comment: While you do have lots of web application ( i think Microsoft recommend to have a maximum of 20 ) i think you can try to add 600 seconds instead of 300 seconds. On the other hand, have you tried creating an new one using powershell? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8560.sharepoint-2010-create-a-new-web-application-and-site-collection-with-windows-powershell.aspx

Comment: I've put 5000 sec.. Let's try PS!

Comment: See if you can add -verbose to the new-spwebapplication cmdlt, might provide you with some more information. Did you get any additional information from the logs then the message above? Anything in the event viewer?

Comment: It seems it worked with PS. But I have a Doubt. Once the WebApp has been created, I tried to Mount a Db on that WeApp: Deatached from the old WApp and attached the new created. But the report int he end of the process(by PS), it seems it hadn't imported any Sites!

Comment: Did you try to create a new root site first in the new web application? Just to try it out to see if it works? Did you get any error messages when mounting the database? Try to create a dummy database and some random site collections and try to move that one to the new web application. And don't forget to drop the connection on the database before mounting it again.

Comment: I didn't get any error while mount Db. yes. I have tried to create a new root SC but when I try to open th root page it returns me the same error: page missing connection

Comment: Sounds like the web application did not get created properly.. do you find any logs when you try to access the site? Did the web application got provisioned correctly in the IIS on all servers in the farm?

Comment: I modified my post and inserted the logs when calling new SC :

Comment: ok. The problem was with URL name set in the WebApp creation. mysite.com:8080 . If I call the webAPP using the hostName it Works like a charm! Do you know what should I set to create many WebApps in in the 80 port with custom URL names?

Comment: I always remove the port from the url as i think they are ugly and does not fill any particular function more than saving you from 1-2 clicks to determin a sites port in IIS..

Comment: To run multiple web applications on the same IP/port, all your web applications need to have a host headers. http://thuansoldier.net/?p=1323